# How to pass parameter which is in object to pathfor in meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router, meteorite

below is my object. I want to send "554b9960f046be881a344779" which is present inside the object.

```
{
  _id: {
    _str : "554b9960f046be881a344779"
   },
  title : "Hello world"
}
```

I tried `<a href="{{pathFor 'article' _id = _id._str}}" > {{title}}  </a>` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you have data context? try with `this`

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'article' _id = this._id._str}}" > {{title}}  </a>
```

It works without `this` too, make sure you have data context available

Comment: Thanks mate. content is not available. it works with and without `this`. Thanks a lot